# Compare with return value from a simple_tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using simple_tag to compute a value in django template. My current code looks like,

```
{% for param_a in params_A %}
  {% for param_b in params_B %}
    <p>{% awesome_tag param_a param_b %}</p>
    # other_stuffs
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to skip `other_stuffs` if the returned value from `awesome_tag` is `foo`.
I know I can do this in the view and then pass the items in the context, but I was wondering if there's any better Django template way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **assignment_tag** for this purpose and store return in some variable and check that variable in template.

```
{% for param_a in params_A %}
  {% for param_b in params_B %}
    <p>{% awesome_tag param_a param_b as result%}</p>

    {% if result != "foo" %}
    # other_stuffs
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

> `assignment_tag` Deprecated since **version 1.9** `simple_tag` can now store
>   results in a template variable and should be used instead.